# (Bash?)Script to check file for numbers and constraint and add offset to number

Tags: bash, sed

I search a tool(chain) (sed/bash/...) in Linux, to achieve the following: Go through a text file (here: XML) find same values, check these values for some rule and correct these values by adding an offset.

A example would be:

```
<!--Origin.txt-->
<Tree>
  <Node foo="600" bar="50" />
  <Node foo="-300" bar="600" />
</Tree>
```

I now wan't to ignore bar completely, but check if e.g. foo is smaller than zero. If it is, add 1000 to foo. If not, leave it.

```
<!--Output.txt-->
<Tree>
  <Node foo="600" bar="50" />
  <Node foo="700" bar="600" />
</Tree>
```

I could write a small python/java program, but I bet there is a faster bash/sed/... script to do this ;)

Comment: My approach btw. works, too. But is too slow for big files, as it takes O(n²): In a shell script I extracted all values via sed, checked them one by one and replaced them if different via sed. Kent's solution is way better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your file with vim, then type:

```
:%s/foo="\zs\(-[0-9]\+\)"\ze/\=submatch(1)+1000/g
```

it should do the job 4 u.

**EDIT**

awk oneliner works for your  new requirement.

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
if($i~/foo="/){ split($i,x,"\""); x[2]=x[2]<100?x[2]+1000:x[2]; $i="foo=\""x[2]"\""; }}1' yourFile
```

in above oneliner, the criteria is the foo attribute value `<100.` you can add criterias as you wish. like `(x[2]>100 && x[2]<700)`

Comment: I quote myself "check if e.g. foo is smaller than zero"... Actually I need a check if a value is in some range... how about that in VIM?

Comment: @powerbar you should describe your requirement correctly in the question.  anyway, see my edit in answer for your new needs (range stuff)

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `infile`:

```
<!--Origin.txt-->
<Tree>
  <Node foo="600" bar="50" />
  <Node foo="-300" bar="600" />
</Tree>
```

Run next command:

```
perl -pe '
  s/\A(\s*<(?i:node)\s+(?i:foo)\s*=\s*")([^"]+)(")/$1 . (defined $2 && $2 < 0 ? $2 + 1000 : $2) . $3/e
' infile
```

And result:

```
<!--Origin.txt-->
<Tree>
  <Node foo="600" bar="50" />
  <Node foo="700" bar="600" />
</Tree>
```

Comment: I got no Perl installed at my rig, but elegant and short solution!

Answer (score 0):

TXR solution:

```
<!--@name-->
<Tree>
@(collect :gap 0)
  <Node foo="@foo" bar="@bar" />
@  (set foo @(int-str foo))
@  (set foo @(if (< foo 0) (+ foo 1000) foo))
@(end)
</Tree>
@(output)
<!--Output.txt-->
<Tree>
@  (repeat)
  <Node foo="@foo" bar="@bar" />
@  (end)
</Tree>
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr xml.txr  -
<!--Origin.txt-->
<Tree>
  <Node foo="600" bar="50" />
  <Node foo="-300" bar="600" />
</Tree>
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
<!--Output.txt-->
<Tree>
  <Node foo="600" bar="50" />
  <Node foo="700" bar="600" />
</Tree>
```

Comment: I didn't know TXR before, but will look into it, when I got some spare time! Thanks for posting a uncommon solution!